# Forms only showing up after submit button is clicked

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've checked similar posts about forms not showing up at all and I've tried applying the fixes, but it did not fix it for me. I have the following:

**stocks.html**:

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ symbol_form }}
  <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Add Stock</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**:

```
class PortfolioStockListView(ListView):
    model = StockPortfolio
    template_name = 'stocks.html'

    def post(self, request):
        symbol_form = StockSymbolForm(request.POST)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            if symbol_form.is_valid():
                model_instance = symbol_form.save(commit=False)
                model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
                model_instance.save()
                return redirect('/')    
            else:
                return render(request, 'stocks.html', {'symbol_form': symbol_form})

        else:
            symbol_form = StockSymbolForm()
            return render(request, 'stocks.html', {'symbol_form': symbol_form})
```

**forms.py**:

```
class StockSymbolForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StockPortfolio
        fields = ['username', 'stock_symbol' , 'stock_qty']
```

**models.py**:

```
class StockPortfolioUser(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usercash = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100000)

class StockPortfolio(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(StockPortfolioUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    stock_qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

How to fix the issue that is causing the forms to hide until the button is clicked? I can share more code from other files if necessary.

Comment: You form is only rendered in the `post` method. You will have to add a `get` as well.

Comment: @KlausD. shouldn't the part where it's not `if request.method == 'POST':` take care of it? since I create a form `symbol_form = StockSymbolForm()` if it's not a post request

Comment: In a class based view get request will be handled by the `get` method. You have only `post`.

Comment: Add a get method if you want to use Class based view. Or change it into a function based method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it to your template overwriting `get_context_data` method

```
class PortfolioStockListView(ListView):
    model = StockPortfolio
    template_name = 'stocks.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(PortfolioStockListView, self).get_context_data(object_list=object_list, **kwargs)
        context['symbol_form'] = StockSymbolForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request):
        ...
```